# docker-machine what ports need forwarding for docker-machine to work?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

What ports need forwarding for docker-machine to work.

I have connected to docker-machine via the local area network and all is working well.

I now try to connect via my public ip and I have forwarded ports 22 and 2376

but when ever i try to create the machine i get

```
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded
```

Can anyone help ?

I couldn't find any specifics on which ports should forwarded so the above ports were what i managed to find out by searching but i think i am missing something

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend running `docker-machine` at all, except for the very specific case of needing a Docker environment on a non-Linux host that can’t run the Docker Desktop application (_e.g._, Windows 7).  What’s the bigger goal you’re trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Sure, my use case is the following. I have docker running on a linux machine, i have things on their, a few website etc. Its actually live on the internet but the machine is next to me. I currently use docker-machine  via the local ip 192.168.1.2 - all is workign well - but when I am not at home, i would like the ability to use docker on my machine at home from my mac - which I currently do but only because the docker-machine is hitting 192.168.1.2.

Comment: What would you not recommend using docker-machine ? is there an alternative to getitng access to my docker i.e. using docker ps, docker-compose up etc - without docker-machine?